# Cannot set "AppAsset baseurl" after settting "request baseUrl" in Yii2 advanced(php framework)

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, base-url

I'm using Yii2 advanced, which have frontend and backend, I'm using two domain to access frontend and backend respectively.

For some reason, I add a baseUrl(`/admin`) to backend, which will cause links like `http://backend.example.com/controller/action` change to `backend.example.com/admin/controller/action`, after this changing, the page can be load correctly

```php
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
        //All requests will add "/admin"，e.g:
        //backend.example.com/controller/action will change to
        //backend.example.com/admin/controller/action
        'baseUrl' => '/admin',
    ],
],
```

But it caused another problem: assets can't load cause it add `/admin` too

[image]

I tried changing the `baseUrl` of `AppAssets` in `backend/assets/AppAsset.php`, but not working

```php
<?php

namespace backend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Main backend application asset bundle.
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

It acts like `$baseUrl` doesn't exists, no matter what value I set to `$baseUrl`, the page just keep requesting `/admin/assets/86321cf/xxxx.js`, how can I remove the `/admin` by modifying settings in `backend/assets/AppAsset.php`?

If I use the `registerJsFile()` method to register js to the page

```php
$this->registerJsFile('plugins/ImageViewer/imageviewer.min.js', ['position' => View::POS_END, 'depends'=>JqueryAsset::class]);
```

it's loading the correct path(which means not adding `/admin` to the path)
[image]

So I was wondering how can I let the page load correct path of assets by changing configurations of `backend/assets/AppAsset.php` or can I solve it by changing configurations in other file?

Comment: public $baseUrl = '@frotnend/web'; in AppAsset

Comment: @vvpanchev Thank you, but just as I said, this option(`$baseUrl` in AppAssets) totally not working if I set the request baseUrl.

Answer (score 0):

$baseUrl in asset -  specifies the URL corresponding to the directory basePath. Like basePath, if you specify the sourcePath property, the asset manager will publish the assets and overwrite this property accordingly.
try to write `@app/backend/web` in baseUrl
since it seems to me that @web after being assigned to the request will be equal to / admin

Comment: Thank you, but in my case, the `$baseUrl` in `AppAssets` totally not working after I set the request baseUrl in `main.php`, no matter what value I set to it, it acts just like doesn't have this property at all. I'm using Yii2 Advaced `2.0.38`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after massive searching and asking people, I solve this myself, it turns out that we can set the `$baseUrl` of `backend/assets/AppAsset.php` in `main.php` in this way

```php
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        //after settting components.request.baseUrl='/admin', the assets url will automatically add "/admin" to its url
        //to avoid this, we can set the asset baseUrl in components.assetManager.baseUrl, set it to '/assets'
        'baseUrl' => '/assets',
    ],
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
        //All requests will add "/admin"，e.g:
        //www.example.com/controller/action will change to
        //www.example.com/admin/controller/action
        'baseUrl' => '/admin',
    ],
    // other configs....
],
```

These two link inspired me:
[Yii - Assets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yii/yii_assets.htm)
[Override Yii2 assetManager config in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110404/override-yii2-assetmanager-config-in-controller)